# Object.create() JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, object, methods, javascript-objects

I am quoting this statement from the JavaScript Definitive Guide book in section 6.1.4 Object.create(). The following statement doesn't seem clear to me.

> You can pass null to create a new object that does not have a prototype, but if you do  this, the newly created object will not inherit anything, not even basic methods like toString() (which means it won't work with the + operator either)

```js
var o2 = Object.create(null) // o2 inherits no props or methods.
```

At this point, I was thinking "Oh Wow". It doesn't inherit any basic methods, when you set Object.create(null). So, I tried to give it a try on console to see if this was really the behavior. I ran the script that is below, and got an unexpected result.

```js
var o2 = Object.create(null);
o2.number = 1;
console.log(o2.number.toString()); // "1"
```

When I ran this code, I was thinking that the .toString was not going to work. I am bit confused or may not understand how things are working here. I was wondering if anyone could clear things up for me. Any help will be appreciated, and thanks for the time for reading my problem. :)

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(o2.number) === Number.prototype`

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `toString` on the number property, which is not the object itself. If you were to try `o2.toString()`, it would not work.

Answer (score 2):

`toString` works in your example because you're running it on a *number*, not the object itself.

It works because it's no different than this:

```
var n = 1;
console.log(n.toString());
```

To see the results of no prototype, try this instead:

```
var o2 = Object.create(null);
console.log(o2.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do ...

```
o2.number = 1
```

... you're creating a property named `number` and adding that property to your `o2` object.

When you do ...

```
o2.number.toString()
```

... you're executing `toString` not on `o2`, but on property `o2.number`.

If you do...

```
console.log(typeof o2.number)
```

... you'll see that `o2.number` has type `number`, and thus has all methods associated with numbers.

If you do ...

```
console.log(typeof o2)
```

... you'll see that `o2` has type `object`.

If you try executing `o2.toString`, you'll get an error and see that this object indeed doesn't have any method named `toString`.

---

#### Note :

In my experience, you probably don't **ever** want to do something like ...

```
var o2 = Object.create(null);
o2.number = 1;
```

What you probably want instead, is something like ...

```
var o2 = Object.create(Object.prototype);
o2.number = 1;
```

... which can can be written more elegantly like ...

```
var o2 = {
    number : 1
};
```

There is little to no advantage with creating objects that do not inherit from `Object.prototype`. And if other people end up using your code, you're likely to confuse the heck out of other developers when they're trying to call eg. `hasOwnProperty` or `toString` on your object and they're getting an error (as they these methods expect to exist for any object).